# Unnecessary horizontal scroll bar getting added in react app

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a carousel using react-bootstrap in my react app. The idea is to have a container with black background within which the carousel shall be placed as shown here

Required container
[image: Required container]

But right after i created a black background div, there's an extra horizontal scroll bar that is being created at the bottom like this

Error being produced
[image: Error being produced]

I do not know where the horizontal scroll bar is coming from. Here I've attached the JS component code and the css pertaining to it.

```
import React from 'react'
import './SlideShow.css'
const SlideShow = () => {
    return(
        <div className = 'slide-container'></div>
    )
}

export default SlideShow
```

CSS:

```
.slide-container{
    width : 100vw;
    height : 50vh;
    background: #050505;
    overflow : hidden;
}
```

Please help me out with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't reset the `body` margin (which e.g. defaults to `8px` in current Chrome).

Two solutions:

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

or

```css
.slide-container { width: calc(100vw - 2 * 8px); }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had initially set the body  margin and padding both to zero, in index.css get rid of the border and it worked also. But as soon as i added the black box , the horizontal bar came up. I tried the second option you gave, i.e to set the width, but it also ain't working. It did reduce the width of the block by 8px but the scroll bar still is remaining.

Comment: I figured it out. I just made the overflow-x hidden, and it removed the bar

Comment: You already had that with `overflow: hidden;`. Is `.slide-container` set to `box-sizing: border-box;`?

Comment: No I didn't set the box-sizing anywhere. Also, instead of setting overflow:hidden inside the css of the slideshow.css file, I set overflow-x:hidden in the index.css. I still didn't quite get why the problem occurred at the first place, but somehow got rectified by doing that change in index.css

Comment: It just clipped the excess, didn't solve the problem completely though

Comment: Try to set the box sizing.